# IdentityUser does not contain a definition for 'name'

Tags: c#, html, postgresql, razor, model-view-controller

The project is creating a webshop. I scaffolded all the Identity files and created an identical view/model (razor page), like the register one from Identity, but now for adding address information. I am trying to create a form in where you can add your address information, so it is not included when registering. To store the data we use PostgresQL and the database is succesfully create through migrations.

Address Model (the error is in user.name = model.name; etc.), he doesn't recognize any of the variables (surname, streetnumber etc.)

```
namespace bytme.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.Manage
{
public class AddressModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<AddressModel> _logger;

    public AddressModel(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<AddressModel> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string StatusMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Invalid input. Maximum is 100 characters.")]
        public string surname { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Street")]
        [StringLength(48, ErrorMessage = "The longest street name in the Netherlands is 48 characters.")]
        public string street { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "House Number")]
        [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "The longest house number in the Netherlands is 5 characters.")]
        public string streetnumber { get; set; }

        //[DataType(DataType.Text)]
        //[Display(Name = "House Number Addition", Description = "For example A or II")]
        //[StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "
        //public string streetnumberadd { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        [StringLength(28, ErrorMessage = "The longest place name in the Netherlands is 28 characters.")]
        public string city { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9][0-9]{3}\s?[a-zA-Z]{2}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid zip, for example: 1234AB")]
        public string zipcode { get; set; }
    }

    public void OnGet(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> AccountChange(InputModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Get the current application user
            var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

            //Update the details
            user.name = model.name;
            user.surname = model.surname;
            user.street = model.street;
            user.streetnumber = model.streetnumber;
            user.city = model.city;
            user.zipcode = model.zipcode;

            // Update user address
            var result = await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
        }

    return RedirectToPage();

}
```

Address View

```
@page
@model AddressModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Add address information";
}
<h4>@ViewData["Title"]</h4>
@Html.Partial("_StatusMessage", Model.StatusMessage)
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form id="change-password-form" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.name"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.surname"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.street"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.street" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.street" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.streetnumber"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.streetnumber" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.streetnumber" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.city"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.city" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.city" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.zipcode"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.zipcode" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.zipcode" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

The UserModel, which is extending to IdentityUser

```
namespace bytme.Models
{
public class UserModel : IdentityUser
    {
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public override string Email { get; set; }
    public override string UserName { get; set; }
    public override string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    public string streetnumber { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
      }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
namespace bytme
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseNpgsql(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddIdentity<UserModel, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `UserManager<IdentityUser>`, while you should use `UserManager<UserModel>` instead. `IdentityUser` instance doesn't have `name` property defined, you defined this property in your `UserModel` class. To fix your issue, you should do two things:

1) Go to `Startup.cs` => `ConfigureServices method`, add:

```
 services.AddIdentity<UserModel, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDatabaseContextClassNameHere>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

2) Inject `UserManager<UserModel> userManager` and `SignInManager<UserModel> signInManager` instead of  `UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager` and `SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager`